# Can a player take both a madness and injury card if his investigator gets reduced to zero stamina and sanity?

Tags: arkham-horror, arkham-horror-dunwich-horror

The Dunwich expansion allows for drawing Madness or Injury cards in place of going insane or being rendered unconscious. Can this be used to draw both Injury and Madness when both go to zero? I believe given that this usually leads to being devoured and that there is no explicit mention of this in the Dunwich rules, the answer is no. Is there any supporting documentation otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The investigator is devoured.**

The [Dunwich Horror rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/f2/e7/f2e7b093-5f2c-4dc5-8f9c-b3663580bb59/dunwich_horror_rules.pdf) reiterates the basic rule

> If an investigator is reduced to both 0 Sanity and 0
>   Stamina at the same time, that investigator is devoured.

Comment: I'd also like to add, as it seems to be relevant, that I have a house rule that if you have a combination of three or more madness/injury cards, your investigator automatically retires from being too debilitated to carry on with the investigation.

Comment: @generalcrispy - The rules allow retirement at 2 madness/injury cards.  Is there a need to force retirement at 3?

Comment: Player exasperation, mostly. Had someone who was manically depressed and concussed, but wanted to trudge on.